# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magenta.protobuf' but I have installed it

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, magenta

I run in the magenta environment on my iMac the python file and I get the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magenta.protobuf'

Though I have tried:

- pip install protobuf
- pip3 install protobuf
- pip install protobuf-compiler
- pip3 install protobuf-compiler

Could anyone please help?

Comment: Type in console `which pip` and `which python`, compare path.

Comment: @OlvinRoght which pip <- /usr/local/bin/pip which python <- /usr/bin/python

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
pip install note-seq
```

then

```
import note_seq.protobuf
```